# OpenPop library how to use TLS

Tags: c#, .net, email, tls1.2

I need to enable tls protocol on openpop library (TLS v.1.2 or TLS v.1.1 ) how to ?

I tried the following code but it did not work:

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
{
    client.Connect("my_hostname", 25, false);
}
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenPop.NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the documentation available here: http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/index.html

The class `Pop3client` has a connect method with a "useSsl" parameter:

```
public void Connect(
   string hostname,
   int port,
   bool useSsl
);
```

Try to connect using the right port and set this parameter as true:

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
{
    client.Connect("your_hostname", 995, true);
}
```

This should validate the server certificate automatically, if you want to do this manually or if you are using a self-signed certificate you can create your own certificate validator:

```
private static bool certificateValidator(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslpolicyerrors)
{
    return true;
}

using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
{
    client.Connect("your_hostname", 995, true, 3000, 3000, certificateValidator);
}
```

More info here: http://hpop.sourceforge.net/exampleOverrideSSL.php

Comment: I need to enable tls not ssl... I see only boolean value for ssl... I don't see one for tls.

Comment: I don't think that makes a difference... It is the same thing (well not really but I am almost sure it is in this case) ;-)

Comment: So I need to set ssl to true and override the function to enable tls???

Comment: Just set it to true and make sure you use the right port, usually SSL/TLS use a different port. You don't need to override the function unless you are using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Thanks... tls 1.2 is supported?

Comment: I'm waiting for me to activate the certified mail with tls, the first of January I will test and publish the outcome.

Comment: Isma, the Tls12 protocol works automatically provided that the framework is equal to 4.6 then with the framework 2.0, 3.5 and 4.0 does not work, for the framework 4.5 it works only if the protocol is specified while with the framework 4.6 even without specifying the protocol everything works on a regular basis.

Comment: Yes it's valid.